# Unserialize cookie variable

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, cookies, setcookie

Thank for viewing my question.

the code:

```
$array = array("zero","one","true","three");
echo $beforecookie = serialize($array); //<<-- IT WORKS;
print_r(unserialize($beforecookie)); //<<--IT WORKS

setcookie('mycookie', $beforecookie, time()+3600);
echo $aftercookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie']; // <<-- it works perfectly same with $beforecookie

$data = unserialize($aftercookie);
print_r($data); //<<--RETURN NOTHING (the problem)
var_dump($data); //<<-- RETURN bool(false);
```

The string(serialized from the array) that I got from cookie can't be unserialized; why? how can I get the array back after set it to the cookie with serialize()? or maybe I missed something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: **NEVER** unserialize cookie data (or any other string that can be manipulated by the user)! It is a major security hole to do so.

Comment: Do you have any errors with unserialize? Check logs

Comment: @ThiefMaster but is it possible or not?

Comment: You cannot read back a cookie during the same execution where you set it if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Indeed, please do not use `unserialize` on user-submitted data. This is easily exploitable with object injection using PHP's __wakeup and __destruct methods. You can use `json_encode/json_decode` instead of `serialize/unserialize`. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection

Comment: Don't forget the magic quotes, you may need to `stripslashes()` before using `unserialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie sets after script execution as well as headers, so you can't access it before page reload.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
setcookie('mycookie', $beforecookie, time()+3600);
echo $aftercookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie'] // <<-- it works perfectly same with $beforecookie
```

The cookie that you set won't be available to the code until the browser refreshes the page.

Also, if you really want to do this, make sure to add a checksum to the cookie that's based on a server-side secret and the contents of the data you're saving into the cookie. Look into `hash_hmac()`. Blindly unserializing a value that you receive from an untrusted source is simply irresponsible.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `base64_encode()` after function `serialize()`.

set:

```
setcookie('name', base64_encode( serialize( $arr ) ) );
```

get:

```
unserialize( base64_decode( $_COOKIE['name']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change only this part of your code:

```
if(!$_COOKIE['mycookie']){
setcookie('mycookie', $beforecookie, time()+3600);
}
```

Then reload the page...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your cookie available instantly (and not after page refresh like the others said) just add

```
$_COOKIE['mycookie'] = $beforecookie;
```

right after this line

```
setcookie('mycookie', $beforecookie, time()+3600);
```

Your cookie will be instantly available :-)